# Разработка (Windows Driver Kit) с чего начать

Tags: c++, c, windows, драйвер, ядро

как правильно отлаживать **driver** или какие способы есть отлаживать **driver** лучше?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Я бы хотел советы от тебя а не от документации если ты этим занимался

Answer (score 1):

Я бы для начала написал обычное приложение и отладил в нём как можно больше кода, а потом уже перенёс это в драйвер.

Вот [тут](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debug-universal-drivers---step-by-step-lab--echo-kernel-mode-) есть подробная пошаговая инструкция по отладке драйверов.

Ещё один [дебаггер (x64dbg)](https://x64dbg.com/).

А это [Get started with drivers on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/) для начала.

Comment: В WDD есть функции, которые могут быть вызваны только в режиме драйвера. Так что не совсем корректно это делать, иначе смысла в драйверах было не так много